# Excel to Dynamics CRM data import using SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I have created a SSIS package for data import from excel to dynamics CRM but now i want to put 2min wait condition for one row to another row import.
eg: i have 10 records in excel sheet, it should import first row and has to wait 2 min for another row after 2 min it should import 2nd row and the wait for 2 min and then 3rd row so on till the last record. can some one help me with script(C#). I'm using script component in SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000);` should accomplish your objective.

The parameter is how long to wait, in milliseconds (so 2 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds)